# Center div using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to center the outer 'div' container using `Flexbox`. I have an unordered list with 3 `li's`. The `li's` width is: `width: calc(100%/3)`. The `ul's` width is `70%`. The problem is that when I try centering the `ul` (`justify-content: center`), it doesn't get centered.

I finally figured out the source of the problem. When I remove the line: `width: calc(100%/3)`, it centers properly. My question is: How can I get it to center properly?

I tried `margin: auto`, but that didn't work.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrr65ajr/), and here's the code snippet:

```css
#flex-container {
  width: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<ul id="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">First</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Second</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I remove the line: width: calc(100%/3), it centers properly

You should not calculate the width when you are using `flex` layout, because that is what `flex` is itself supposed to do.

1. If you are looking to align the text inside of the `li`s then `text-align` is what you need. You should also remove the `width` from the `li`s and use the `flex` property instead.

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#flex-container {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 70%; display: flex; 
}
li {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;   
}
```

```html
<ul id="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">First</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Second</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Third</li>
</ul>
```

2. If you are looking to have variable width `li`s then `justify-content` is what you need. You should control the width via the `width` property and use `flex` property as required to expand or shrink.

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#flex-container {
    list-style-type: none; width: 70%;
    display: flex; justify-content: center;
    background-color: #eee;
}
li {
    flex: 0 0 auto; width: 15%;
    background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid #fff;
}
li:first-child { width: 20%; }
li:last-child { width: 30%; }
```

```html
<ul id="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">First</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Second</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I make them all the same width, with only 3 in 1 row?

Comment: @Jessica: They will be of the same width by default as in the first case in my answer. What do you mean by only 3 in a row? As per your question you have only 3 `li`s. Do you have indeterminate number of `li`s? Do you want to wrap those `li`s with 3 each in a row? If yes, then you should have specified it clearly in your question. Please update your question and include all necessary details and what exactly are you trying to do. I am still unsure of your use-case. You have not yet clarified which of the two cases in my answer fits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hrr65ajr/2/

```css
#flex-container {
    width: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: auto;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">First</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Second</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm trying to center `#flexContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
<ul id="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">First</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Second</li>
    <li class="flex-item">Third</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    display:flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#flex-container {
    width: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: tomato;
    width: calc(100%/3);
}
```